# Point in Polygon operation for 100G of data

Tags: postgis, shapely

I have lat/lon point locations for over a billion points, all based in the US. For each point I would like to generate a dataset that links them to their county and to their MSA according to US Census Shapefiles.

My question is how to do this efficiently? I have access to a research computing server, postgis, shapely and statistical software.

Comment: Is your data have a spatial index in postgis?

Comment: no, at the moment its just a flatfile.

Comment: Python would be efficient, not sure if there's an easier way. Once you have your County shapefiles, create an array in Python, loop through and verify for a given point whether it falls within the County boundary at the index, and if so store census data along with the XY coordinates into another array, then create point feature classes with the array.

Comment: Break it up into batches and run them one per core. Divide and conquer approach! Perhaps an intersect/overlay would be more suitable for the volume of data.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks! I'm new to PostGIS -- what do do mean by "Intersect/overlay"? I'm planning to use "St_Contains" -- is that a bad idea?

Comment: In ESRI it's a geoprocessing operation either Intersect or Identity. QGIS has something similar and can access PostGIS data - I know from experience. So if a tool exists in QGIS why reinvent the wheel, unless of course there's a good reason to. Do you have access to ArcGIS? This sort of thing is bread & butter for ArcPY!